# Flutter/dart: how to render LinkedMap<dynamic, dynamic> to listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this data from api that then gives me a _JsonMap response which I then convert to LinkedMap<dyanmic, dynamic> by doing:

```
final data = Map.from(response.data);
```

Now I have this LinkedMap<dyanmic, dynamic> data which looks like this.

```
{
  Product1: {
      name: 'name',
      description: 'description',
      Promos: {
          Price1: {
             amount: 999,
             metadata: {
                dateStart: 2022-11-23
                dateEnd: 2022-11-25
                promoName: test,
             }
          }
          Price2: {
             amount: 999,
             metadata: {
                dateStart: 2022-11-23
                dateEnd: 2022-11-25
                promoName: test,
             }
          }
          Price3: {
             amount: 999,
             metadata: {
                dateStart: 2022-11-23
                dateEnd: 2022-11-25
                promoName: test,
             }
          }
      }
  }

  Product2: {
      name: 'name',
      description: 'description',
      Promos: {
          Price1: {
             amount: 999,
             metadata: {
                dateStart: 2022-11-23
                dateEnd: 2022-11-25
                promoName: test,
             }
          }
          Price2: {
             amount: 999,
             metadata: {
                dateStart: 2022-11-23
                dateEnd: 2022-11-25
                promoName: test,
             }
          }
          Price3: {
             amount: 999,
             metadata: {
                dateStart: 2022-11-23
                dateEnd: 2022-11-25
                promoName: test,
             }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Now what i'm trying to do is Map the Producst - get to their Promos - get the all Prices - then get to their metadata and display dateStart, dateEnd, promoName to my listview.builder. any ideas?

response.data

```
       {
  "Product1":{
  "name":"name",
  "description":"test",
  "Promos":{
     "Price1":{
        "amount":"999",
        "metadata":{
           "dateStart":"2022-11-23",
           "dateEnd":"2022-11-25",
           "promoName":"test"
        }
     },
     "Price2":{
        "amount":"999",
        "metadata":{
           "dateStart":"2022-11-23",
           "dateEnd":"2022-11-25",
           "promoName":"test"
        }
     },
     "Price3":{
        "amount":"999",
        "metadata":{
           "dateStart":"2022-11-23",
           "dateEnd":"2022-11-25",
           "promoName":"test"
        }
     }
  }
  },
  "Product2":{
  "name":"name",
  "description":"test",
  "Promos":{
     "Price1":{
        "amount":"999",
        "metadata":{
           "dateStart":"2022-11-23",
           "dateEnd":"2022-11-25",
           "promoName":"test"
        }
     },
     "Price2":{
        "amount":"999",
        "metadata":{
           "dateStart":"2022-11-23",
           "dateEnd":"2022-11-25",
           "promoName":"test"
        }
     },
     "Price3":{
        "amount":"999",
        "metadata":{
           "dateStart":"2022-11-23",
           "dateEnd":"2022-11-25",
           "promoName":"test"
        }
     }
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the response.data?

Comment: @Paulo it is the same from above but in _JsonMap type

Comment: Need the json format

Comment: @Paulo added json format

Comment: Your response data is not well formatted as it should be.

Comment: Do you have `Product` class that has a nested `List<Price>` class?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the response.data. it's just not common way a response is structure. Look Through on to approach sure response in the answer i posted;

Answer (score 0):

First your response data should look like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "Product 1",
    "description": "test",
    "promos": [
      {
        "name": "Price 1",
        "amount": "999",
        "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
        "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
        "promoName": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "Price 2",
        "amount": "999",
        "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
        "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
        "promoName": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "Price 3",
        "amount": "999",
        "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
        "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
        "promoName": "test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Product 2",
    "description": "test",
    "promos": [
      {
        "name": "Price 1",
        "amount": "999",
        "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
        "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
        "promoName": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "Price 2",
        "amount": "999",
        "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
        "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
        "promoName": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "Price 3",
        "amount": "999",
        "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
        "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
        "promoName": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

then you need to serialize the reponse data
`sample_model.dart`

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Products {
  Products({
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.promos,
  });

  String name;
  String description;
  List<Promo> promos;

  factory Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Products(
        name: json["name"],
        description: json["description"],
        promos: List<Promo>.from(json["promos"].map((x) => Promo.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "description": description,
        "promos": List<dynamic>.from(promos.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Promo {
  Promo({
    required this.name,
    required this.amount,
    required this.dateStart,
    required this.dateEnd,
    required this.promoName,
  });

  String name;
  String amount;
  DateTime dateStart;
  DateTime dateEnd;
  String promoName;

  factory Promo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Promo(
        name: json["name"],
        amount: json["amount"],
        dateStart: DateTime.parse(json["dateStart"]),
        dateEnd: DateTime.parse(json["dateEnd"]),
        promoName: json["promoName"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "amount": amount,
        "dateStart":
            "${dateStart.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${dateStart.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${dateStart.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "dateEnd":
            "${dateEnd.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${dateEnd.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${dateEnd.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "promoName": promoName,
      };
}
```

then use the `sample_model.dart` method on your controller or view

```
final  data = List<Products>.from(response.data.map((x) => Products.fromJson(x)));
```

finally, on ListView.builder.

**Updated** to nested ListView.builder for 300 promos use case as mention by @theodore

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: controller.response.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var product = controller.data[index];
      return Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(product.name),
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: product.promos.length,
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(product.promos[index].name),
                      Text(product.promos[index].amount),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

**Gist:** **Complete code** [here](https://gist.github.com/SteplerPaulo/6eb5c77c8af9a5440ae2c3aedc330273). Copy & paste it on **dartpad.dev** to see the result

Comment: This approach is not resilient for the current structure of the response. I strongly don't recommend it.

Comment: The most basic problem of software development is the team on FE doesn't want to communicate with BE Devs, then create out of this world solutions just to make it work. With this approach expect more  unmaintainable code in the future. :)

Comment: This answer is not useful. Some Standard API e.g Microsoft Azure Auth Lib(@azure/msal-node) returns such response. Even your approach in populating the promos name/amount is not resilient(what have if you have 300 promos) .

Comment: You just have to wrap in another listview.builder. Just did it in the most simple way so the questioner will understand it better. Will update my answer for your 300 promos usecase

Answer (score 0):

Paulo's answer is basically correct. Though you would probably want to automate those codes, since `toJson` and `fromJson` methods are mechanically repeated for each data class.

The package [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) will do the trick. In your case, your data model is simple and you can write the code by hand. Its effectiveness is more evident for more complex data models.

So it is up to your judgement to use hand-written or automated solution, or a mix of both.

Comment: Thanks Ashkan. For me I used quicktype.io for the serialization. But would love to implement json_serializable in the future. :)

Comment: I'm very familiar with that approach. I myself use https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart. What happens when you can't make contact with the backend? Your answer becomes useless.

Comment: I hope you get my point. Am just talking from experience.

Answer (score -1):

Just Copy and Paste; Then carefully Study it;
The Trick is to use MapEntry i.e Convert your data to a List by doing data.entries.toList();

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grouped_list/grouped_list.dart';

final data = {
  "Product1": {
    "name": "theodore",
    "description": "test",
    "Promos": {
      "Price1": {
        "amount": "999",
        "metadata": {
          "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
          "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
          "promoName": "test"
        }
      },
      "Price2": {
        "amount": "999",
        "metadata": {
          "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
          "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
          "promoName": "test"
        }
      },
      "Price3": {
        "amount": "999",
        "metadata": {
          "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
          "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
          "promoName": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Product2": {
    "name": "cynthia",
    "description": "test",
    "Promos": {
      "Price1": {
        "amount": "999",
        "metadata": {
          "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
          "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
          "promoName": "test"
        }
      },
      "Price2": {
        "amount": "999",
        "metadata": {
          "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
          "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
          "promoName": "test"
        }
      },
      "Price3": {
        "amount": "999",
        "metadata": {
          "dateStart": "2022-11-23",
          "dateEnd": "2022-11-25",
          "promoName": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Grouped List View Example'),
        ),
        body: GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
          elements: data.entries.toList(),
          groupBy: (element) => element.value["name"],
          groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value2.compareTo(value1),
          itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
              item1['name'].compareTo(item2['name']),
          order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
          useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
          groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              value,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (c, element) {
            return Column(
              children: (element.value["Promos"].entries.toList()
                      as List<MapEntry>)
                  .map((promo) => Card(
                        elevation: 8.0,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: ListTile(
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                            title: Text(promo.key +
                                "-" +
                                " " +
                                promo.value["metadata"]["promoName"]),
                            subtitle: Text(promo.value["metadata"]["dateEnd"]),
                            trailing: Text(promo.value["amount"]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```